# Как сделать функцию операций на элементах lazy list (aka "Streams")?

Tags: функции, функциональное-программирование, ocaml

Мне нужно сделать функцию, которая принимает две lazy list и оператор и применяет этот оператор к одинаковым по индексу элементам lazy list. Например, [1;2;3], [2;3;4;5] +, вернет [3;5;7;5]. Lazy list записан в виде обычных для удобства чтения.

Вот мой код, в нем возникает ошибка после function() -> , This expression has type int lazyList * int lazyList * char -> int lazyList but an expression was expected of type int lazyList:

```
type 'a lazyList = LNil | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList);;

let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator = function
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '+' -> LCons(xA + xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '+')
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '-' -> LCons(xA - xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '-')
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '/' -> LCons(xA / xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '/')
| LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB), '*' -> LCons(xA * xB, function() -> ldzialanie xfA xfB '*')
| LNil, LNil, _ -> LNil
| LNil, LCons(x, xf), _ -> LCons(x, function() -> xf())
| LCons(x, xf), LNil, _ -> LCons(x, function() -> xf())
| LCons(_), LCons(_), _ -> failwith "Not existible operator"
;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного странновато вы его реализовываете, но как-то так

```
type 'a lazyList =
  | LCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList)
  | LNil


let rec ldzialanie listA listB operator =
  match (listA, listB) with
  | LCons(xA, xfA), LCons(xB, xfB) ->
     LCons(operator xA xB, function () -> ldzialanie (xfA ()) (xfB ()) operator)
  | LCons(x, xf), LNil -> LCons(x, xf)
  | LNil, LCons(x, xf) -> LCons(x, xf)
  | LNil, LNil -> LNil


let print list =
  let rec print_rec = function
    | LCons (a, xf) ->
       Printf.printf "%d " a;
       print_rec (xf ())
    | LNil -> ()
  in
  print_rec list ;
  print_newline ()
```

Исправил ваш код, к тому же сделал оператор функцией `'a -> 'a -> 'a`, а не символом, которой ограничивает ее работой только с ленивыми списками целых чисел. Добавил функцию `print`, которая работает только со списками целых, но она к задаче не относится, приведена только для отладки, поэтому сделал так для простоты.

Пример использования

```
# let a = LCons (1, fun () -> LCons (2, fun () -> LCons (3, fun () -> LNil))) ;;
# let b = LCons (2, fun () -> LCons (3, fun () -> LCons (4, fun () -> LCons (5, fun () -> LNil)))) ;;
# print a ;;
1 2 3 
- : unit = ()
# print b ;;
2 3 4 5 
- : unit = ()
# print (ldzialanie a b (+)) ;;
3 5 7 5 
- : unit = ()
```